# Not able to import a file which is present in same directory

Tags: python, import

I have flaskblog.py and forms.py in same directory sample. But when I try the code "from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm", I compile time error in PyCharm.

I was successfully able to import like this: from sample.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

After this when I try to run the code using python flaskblog.py, I am seeing the below error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\ksrihari\PycharmProjects\myFlaskStudy\sample>python flaskblog.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flaskblog.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sample.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample'


from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from sample.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'a515c030528fbddb08443cea4e6fd96c'

posts = [
    {
        'author':'Corey Schafer',
        'title':'Blog Post1',
        'content':'First Blog Post',
        'date_posted':'18, May 2019',
        'last_updated_date':f"{datetime.datetime.now()::%d, %b %Y}"
    },
    {
        'author':'Srihari K S S',
        'title':'Blog Post2',
        'content':'Second Blog Post',
        'date_posted':'18, May 2019',
        'last_updated_date':f"{datetime.datetime.now()::%d, %b %Y}"
    }
]

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')

@app.route("/register")
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    return render_template('register.html', form = form, title = 'Register')

@app.route("/login")
def register():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', form = form, title = 'Login')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)[enter image description here][1]
```

[Pycharm Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckuXL.png)

Comment: When using from forms import Registration..... , I am seeing the error Unresolved reference in PyCharm

Comment: Python uses the location where it runs as its base import location. How are you running the python file?  If you run it like `python myfile.py` than it is a different issue, but if you run it like `python app/myfile.py` than you will get this error because your file is running in the directory above `app` not within `app`.

Comment: I am running it as 
C:\Users\ksrihari\PycharmProjects\myFlaskStudy\sample>python flaskblog.py

Comment: If you're already in the `sample` directory, then you don't want `from sample.forms import x`, you want `from forms import x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a package (directory with a **init**.py file) you import it like this:

```
from package_name.forms import ClassName
```

if it is not a package, and just separate modules, you can import it like this:

```
from forms import ClassName
```

Cheers!